# создание Bottom tab activity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view

Я создал bottom tab activity и три фрагмента , что надо прописать в main_activity, чтобы подключить эти фрагменты и при нажатии на item открывался один из фрагментов?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:

                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:

                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

}

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Чтоб видеть что вы уже сделали

Comment: скриншотом думаю понятней будет

Comment: @fantik не добавляйте код скриншотами. Скопируйте с нормальным форматированием и вставьте в вопрос.

Comment: хорошо, извините